# Como capturar dados para somente alimentar uma lista com VTEX

Tags: javascript, ajax, e-commerce

Fiz esse código js para pegar os dados dos inputs (ESTA PEGANDO OK ESSA PARTE) da pagina e enviar para VTEX (NÃO ESTÁ ENVIANDO). Deve ser algum detalhe que tenha me esquecido. Já fiz varios js para capturar os dados, cadastrar na VTEX e depois disparar um evento (MANDAR EMAIL PARA O USUÁRIO) e nunca tive problema. O porém e que esse js não precisa ter nenhum evento, ou seja, não enviará email para o usuário, eu quero somente coletar os dados.

```
(function($){
if(typeof newsButtonClick == "function"){
    newsButtonClick = function(instanceId) {
        var clientName = $('#' + instanceId + ' .newsletter-client-name').val();
        var clientEmail = $('#' + instanceId + ' .newsletter-client-email').val();
        var internalPage = $('#' + instanceId + '#newsInternalPage').val();
        var internalPart = $('#' + instanceId + '#newsInternalPart').val();
        var internalCampaign = $('#' + instanceId + '#newsInternalCampaign').val();         
        if (clientName.length > 0 && newsCheckEmail(clientEmail)) {
            var dataToPost = { newsletterClientName: (clientName == originalNewsNameFieldValue ? "" : clientName), newsletterClientEmail: clientEmail, newsInternalPage: internalPage, newsInternalPart: internalPart, newsInternalCampaign: internalCampaign };
            var url = '/no-cache/Newsletter.aspx';
            newsletterAjaxRequest('POST', url, dataToPost, '#' + instanceId + '.newsletter', '');              
            var now = new Date();
            var y = now.getFullYear(),
            m = now.getMonth(),
            d = now.getDate(),
            fullDate = y+"-"+(m+1)+"-"+d
            try {          
                    lista : { 
                        nm_lista : "teste";
                        nm_email : clientEmail;
                        nome : clientName;
                        atualizar : "1";
                        dt_cadastro : {
                            valor : fullDate;
                            atualizar : "1";
                        }                                          
                    }                                       
            console.log("ok");
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);                
            }                          
        }
    }
} 
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Faltava a seguinte linha:

```
__blc['id'] = "";
```